# How to install universal application in 2G iPhone

Tags: iphone, universal-binary

i have created an universal application using xcode 3.2.4. in my build setting i have set "target device" as 3.1.2. This application is working fine with iPhone 3G, iPhone 4 and iPod touch 3G. But i am facing "Unsigned" error if i try to install my universal application into my 2G iPhone which have iOS 3.1.3 I have included 2G iPhone UID into provisioning file. But still getting same error.
please guide me as how to over come this issue and make my universal app to work in 2G devices also.

thanks in advance.
Ram

Comment: No iPhone can run iOS 3.2.1, 3.2.x is iPad only.

Comment: @coob i have corrected my post as my 2G iPhone having iOS 3.1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned seems to imply you still have an issue with your provisioning profile.  Open the Organizer in XCode, click on the device on the left, and look at the provisioning profiles that are associated with it to verify that the one to which you assigned that device's UID is actually on the device.

Comment: i have included the UID of 2G iPhone in my mobile provisioning file.  But still i couldn't install.  if i create an application using xcode 3.4.2, the apps can run in 3G devices?

Comment: 1.  You associate the UID to the provisioning profile in iTunes Connect.  2.  You download the PP and drag it onto XCode to make it available to compile with.   3.  You set in info.plist and your Project Settings to use that PP.  4.  You install that PP on your device via XCode Organizer.  5.  Build and run.